# React Native: Use of spread operator in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In a React Native app, I saw the following code:

```
<View {...input}/>
```

where

```
input = {style: {...}}
```

In the first line, they use the spread operator but then enclose it within curly braces. Wouldn't this be like writing

```
<View {style: {...}}/>
```

instead of the correct

```
<View style={...}/>
```

Comment: I thought, the curly brackets are there, because the spread operator is JS and to use JS within JSX you need to put it in curly brackets. So that it is recognized as plain JS.